# Flutter: Lost connection to device in iOS Simulator Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

Following the steps of a tutorial (*git/flash_chat_app*), I got stuck when I write the code to get the connection with Firebase. The app runs very well (simple app). The problem is on the "`Login`" & "`Register`" buttons. After writing the email and password, **when I press the button** to submit the app crushes and I've got a simple "`Lost connection to device`" message. However, on Firebase the email is registered. So there is the connection but the app just crushes every time... I've read the posts about this subject but nothing similar to this issue.

I hope you can help, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok found it...the whole day.
If anybody else faces this issue, I solved it just downgrading flutter (I had the last version 1.27xxxxx till this day). So on 1.26 I have no issue for the moment.